# updating a table from another table and update transaction in a log

Tags: java, mysql

I have a database with three tables `stud_first`, `stud_second` and `stud_audit` both `stud_first` and `stud_second` have the same column names which is

```
name,
stud-id,
age,
class
number_of-course_taken
```

I want `stud_second` to always take any data inserted in `stud_firs`t and at the same time `stud_audit` should keep record of the data copied i.e a log of the name of students and the time they were copied or deleted from `stud_firs`t to `stud_second`.  The columns in `stud_audit` should look like this

```
name,
time copied
```

I want to do it `mysql` alone or combine it with `java`

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but this may be enough to get you started in the right direction...

```
DELIMTER $$
CREATE TRIGGER stud_first_ar 
AFTER INSERT ON stud_first
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO stud_second
  (`name`, `stud-id`, `age`,`class`,`number_of-course_taken`) 
  VALUES
  (NEW.`name`,NEW.`stud-id`,NEW.`age`,NEW.`class`,NEW.`number_of-course_taken`);

  INSERT INTO stud_audit (`name`, `time copied`) 
  VALUES (NEW.`name`,UTC_TIMESTAMP());

END$$
```

You could use `NOW()` in place of `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`, if you aren't concerned with timezone issues.

The choice of column names containing dashes and spaces is non-standard... it's allowed, but it's usually easier when you avoid doing that.

I would actually have just one audit table, rather than two separate ones. It could be copy of the table with additional columns for "action" (identifying whether the change was due to an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE), "actor" (identifying the process or user that caused the action, and a UTC timestamp.

You may want to consider "audit" triggers for UPDATE and DELETE actions as well, where you have the special "`OLD.`" record available.

Again, not a complete answer, but this may be enough to get you started in the right direction.